# CPT relations use in permalinks under single post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have a complicated question related to CPT and the permalink structure.
So, I have two CPT's:
 1. Cities
 2. Properties
Now, the relation is Cities parent to property. So when crate a single city like London, I assign related properties from the child CPT.

Everything work's fine, but when it comes to permalinks, I need to show the chosen city (which is a single post type) above the properties related to it. 
permalink need to be like that: website/cities/london(single cities-CPT)/property/post-name(single property-CPT).

For one week, I was looking around and didn't find any solutions.
Tnx to anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you show your `register_post_type()` code for both the CPTs? How do you relate the CPTs; using a custom field? If so, what's the code?

Comment: Hi, **sorry** I wasn't specific, I create them with "jet engine" some plugin which creates simple CPT's. the plugin generates the relation key for me. so for example: One key can be - relation_0c2f5c1d450f94dfdd58321582656f20 I try to rewrite the permalink rules:   `(function custom_rewrite_basic(). { <br/>add_rewrite_rule('^cities/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?property=$matches[2]',   'top'); }. add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic')`  i try something like that

Comment: Adding the rewrite rule is easy, but generating the custom permalink requires knowing the parent post (the 'cities' post that is parent of the 'properties' post). But with such relation key, it's hard to identify the parent post since the relation key is dynamic in this format: `relation_<hash>`. If it's like `_cities_id` (i.e. static key), then that would be easy.

Comment: Also, Jet Engine is a paid plugin - and I don't have it, so unless if the key `relation_0c2f5c1d450f94dfdd58321582656f20` is actually static for all 'properties' posts, you should contact their support for a way to get the parent 'cities' post. Also, I'm assuming the key is a metadata..

Comment: Hi tnx for your replay.  
The key is a static key. use it in some macros to loop related children.  
And yes, the key is metadata.  
Tnx again, really appreciate your help

Comment: This key is the actual relation between 'cities' and 'property' is parent-children relation.

Comment: So I want to confirm, for *each* 'properties' post, the meta `relation_0c2f5c1d450f94dfdd58321582656f20 ` is present in that post? And what's the value of that meta? A post ID, slug or? Also, what are the CPT slugs - are they `cities` and `properties`? Are you able to export the CPT settings/code using the plugin?